# NullPointerException during Sonar analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Using Java 11, Maven 3.6.3, sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184, SonarQube 8.9.6, a Sonar analysis
`mvn sonar:sonar`
yields

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project xxx:
Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher:
Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules:
NullPointerException
```

No trace is issued in the SonarQube log files.

Answer (score 0):

Cause : probable bug in the SonarQube server.

Solution :
as reported in [this SonarQube community thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/nullpointerexception-after-updating-to-9-2-4/56895/11), the solution is to re-create the ElasticSearch index. The procedure, as per [the SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/#header-3) (version 9.3) is:

```
    Stop your server
    Remove the contents of the $SQ_HOME/data/es7 directory
    Start your server
```